# NFS Shares on an unmounted file system

Tags: mount, nfs, busybox

I am trying to run a file system check.

First, I want to unmount the device.

```
umount /dev/md2
umount: /dev/md2: not mounted
```

Seems good.
Then, I want to run the check:

```
e2fsck -fp -C 0 /dev/md2 
/dev/md2 is mounted.  

WARNING!!!  Running e2fsck on a mounted filesystem may cause
SEVERE filesystem damage.

Do you really want to continue (y/n)? no
```

What's going on here? Is this device mounted or not?

System is a QNAP, firmware 4.2.4, this is based on busybox.

```
busybox | head -1
BusyBox v1.01 (2017.12.07-18:28+0000) multi-call binary
```

**EDIT:**
`mount -l` shows some NFS4 shares, for this device. unmount on that shares did the trick! But how can the device be unmounted, but the shares are still there at the same time?

`fstab` looks like this:

```
# cat /etc/fstab 
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# <file system> <mount pt>     <type>   <options>         <dump> <pass>
/dev/ram       /              ext2  defaults         1      1
proc        /proc          proc     defaults      0  0
none            /dev/pts        devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0       0
```

`mtab` looks like this:

```
# cat /etc/mtab
/proc /proc proc rw 0 0
none /dev/pts devpts rw,gid=5,mode=620 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw 0 0
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs rw,size=64M 0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw 0 0
tmpfs /share tmpfs rw,size=16M 0 0
none /proc/bus/usb usbfs rw 0 0
/dev/sda4 /mnt/ext ext3 rw 0 0
/dev/md9 /mnt/HDA_ROOT ext3 rw,data=ordered 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/rf/nd tmpfs rw,size=1m 0 0
nfsd /proc/fs/nfsd nfsd rw 0 0
rpc_pipefs /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs rpc_pipefs rw 0 0
tmpfs /share/NFSv=4 tmpfs rw,size=16M 0 0
/share/MD2_DATA/[..] /share/NFSv=4/[..] none rw,bind 0 0
/share/MD2_DATA/[..] /share/NFSv=4/[..] none rw,bind 0 0
/share/MD2_DATA/[..] /share/NFSv=4/[..] none rw,bind 0 0
/share/MD2_DATA/[..] /share/NFSv=4/[..] none rw,bind 0 0
```

umounting the NFS shares does the trick, but how can I have NFS shares 'mounted' if nfs is not running and the underlying device is not mounted?

Comment: What's the output of `mount`?

Comment: Is autofs/automount installed?

Comment: Yes, there are clients in the network mounting via automount. But I stopped the nfs server and unmounted the underlying device. Still the mounts are there...